# Нужна ли запятая? 8

Tags: пунктуация

*В рейтинге качества жизни (?) среди европейских городов 8-й год подряд первое место занимает Вена.*

Интонационно очень хочется поставить в этом месте запятую, но вроде как и не надо. Что скажете?

Comment: Есть рейтинг городов мира по уровню качества жизни. Ваша конструкция "рейтинг качества жизни среди европейских городов" не кажется мне корректной.

Comment: Я задал отдельный вопрос об употреблении слова "рейтинг" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432967/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В рейтинге качества жизни среди европейских городов // 8-й год подряд первое место занимает Вена.**

(Или, может быть,  лучше: В рейтинге качества жизни среди европейских городов // первое место 8-й год подряд занимает Вена.

В указанном месте нет паузы, сочетание "*в рейтинге качества жизни среди европейских городов*" составляет единую конструкцию.

Знаки препинания здесь отсутствуют: **это простое неосложненное предложение**, оно делится небольшой паузой на две части (интонационные фразы), но эта пауза запятой не обозначается.

Примечание.

[Уровень и качество жизни, их основные показатели | refleader.ru](http://refleader.ru/merujgqasrna.html)

**Качество жизни** – это именно  качественные показатели (качество товаров, услуг, труда, управления, образования и т. д.).  **Уровень жизни** – это количественная характеристика,  социальный стандарт, характеризующий степень удовлетворения физических и социальных потребностей людей.

Comment: Рейтинг (упорядоченный список) городов, а не качества, и не уровня.

Comment: В крайнем случае, рейтинг качества жизни в городах

Comment: Возможно, имеется в виду просто "рейтинг качества жизни", тогда "первое место среди европейских городов занимает Вена". Немного смешно, будто бы неевропейские города из рейтинга не принимаем во внимание, а среди европейских Вена на первом месте.

Comment: Именно так! В данном контексте рейтинг проводился только среди европейских стран.

Comment: Проводился? Разве рейтинг - мероприятие?

Comment: @М_Г разве только мероприятия проводятся? По-моему, значение "провести" в данном контексте вполне ясно.

Comment: @Sibylla, опять этот ваш "аргумент" насчет "паузы". Вспомните сами мильён случаев, когда пауза есть, а запятой нет, и не вводите больше людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @Niemand, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Я лично Вам десятый раз говорю, что в паузах надо разбираться и знать, какие паузы следует обозначать запятой, а какие нет.  Запомните: ПАУЗЫ БЫВАЮТ РАЗНЫЕ.   Так что возьмите свой "мильон" случаев и разделите его на три группы: а) есть пауза и запятая ; б) нет паузы, есть запятая;в) есть пауза, нет запятой. Это совсем не трудно, я уверена, что Вы справитесь.

Comment: @Sybilla, какие паузы следует обозначать, а какие нет – об этом говорит синтаксис, а не  "интонация".

Comment: А вот РОЗЕНТАЛЬ часто говорит о связи между наличием паузы и запятой, то есть ориентируется на интонацию, например: 3) после союза но запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: Но, если далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.); Но когда он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

Comment: Один подпункт – это у вас означает "часто"? Вот вы ссылаетесь на "интонацию" действительно часто, причем почти всегда без всяких оснований. И потом – не сравнивайте: примеры у Розенталя не в пример сложнее, чем у нашего автора, поэтому ваша ссылка на "интонацию" совершенно ни к селу ни к городу; вполне достаточно ответа: запятая не нужна – нет причин для постановки.

Comment: Повторяю, если вы ещё не поняли: Розенталь часто упоминает интонацию в своих правилах, я вам привела ОДИН из примеров (остальные сами ищите). Еще чаще об интонации говорится в современных учебных пособиях, только вы их не читаете. И не надо всех мерить по себе и решать, кому и что достаточно. Кстати, дайте мне ссылочку на этот ваш лозунг "нет причин для постановки знаков препинания", в каком авторитетном источнике вы его прочитали?

Comment: Если вам для "мама мыла раму" нужны "авторитетные источники" – извините, помочь ничем не могу. Может, в современных учебных пособиях об этом говорится? Тогда вам и карты в руки.

Comment: Мама с рамой тут ни при чем, речь идет о принципиальном для пунктуации вопросе: нужно или не нужно объяснять отсутствие знаков препинания. Например: Он жил в большой светлой комнате. Комната была большая, светлая. Нужно объяснять отсутствие запятой в первом случае?

Comment: Не уходите от вопроса. В предложении автора таких "тонкостей" нет, там именно "мама мыла раму", и не больше.

Comment: Да,  надо было закончить разговор еще на Розентале,   а ещё лучше вообще его не начинать ввиду абсолютной бесполезности. В дальнейшем с моей стороны можете рассчитывать только на одну реплику.  И за речью своей следите,  не заставляйте модераторов вас редактировать.

Comment: Когда нечего ответить, можно даже и одну реплику не тратить.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, автор хотел сказать что-та похожее на:

**В рейтинге качества жизни Вена занимает первое место среди европейских городов (уже) 8-й год подряд.**

Но порядок слов в оригинальном предложении настолько отличается от нормального, что принять его невозможно, по-моему. К тому же из предложения как бы следует, что неевропейские города из рейтинга мы не принимаем во внимание, а вот среди европейских Вена на первом месте. Это ли имел в виду автор предложения?

Вероятно, мы имеем дело просто с плохим переводом с иностранного языка.

И еще: европейские - со строчной буквы , а восьмой цифрами - 8-й.

Comment: Если изменить порядок слов, то меняется структура предложения, а это связно с переносом логических ударений. В приведенном варианте структура имеет вид  тема-рема, ударение падает на конец каждой из двух фраз, то есть "городов" и "Вена", а это важно. В вашем же варианте серьезная перестройка под классическую структуру: обстоятельственный детерминант в начале предложения,  а потом тема-рема.

Comment: @Sibylla а можно подробнее узнать об этих логических ударениях и "темах-ремах"?

Comment: Тема-рема - это актуальное членение предложения, например:http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/985091/page:33/ . Теория интонации (деление на фразы, фразовое и логическое ударение и т..д. ) в разных источниках дается по-разному. В Сети я не смогла найти чего-нибудь простого и понятного на эту тему.

Comment: В двух словах это выглядит так. Предложение делится на фразы - отрезки речи, разделенные паузами. Каждая фраза имеет фразовое (тоническое) ударение на одном из входящих в нее слов (это ударение и связывает слова во фразу так же,  как словесное ударение связывает слоги в слово). Тоническое ударение - это повышение или понижение тона. Обычно тоническое ударение падает на конечное слово фразы, но может смещаться и на другие слова. Перестановка  слов  ведет к изменению тонических ударений, таким образом  можно выделить  нужные слова.

Comment: @М_Г  Собственно, об ошибках. "И еще: европейские - со строчной буквы , а восьмой цифрами - 8-й"...  Вы же  сами делали правку,  что ж не изменили? Там еще и "что скажите?"!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, "что скажите" не заметил, каюсь, а остальное оставил как полезный пример, в котором мы делаем разбор ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

> > Интонационно очень хочется поставить в этом месте запятую, но вроде как и не надо.

Интонация ни при чём. Пунктуация обусловлена синтаксисом (строением предложения), а не интонацией. Не путайте разные вещи: *исторически* пунктуация и правда обозначала паузы ("препинания") в речи, но сейчас (и уже давным-давно) такого и в помине нет. Руководствуйтесь синтаксисом, а не интонацией, как, собственно, и учат учебники и справочники.