# Рейтинг — показатель или список?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Словари говорят, что рейтинг — некий показатель, по которому можно сортировать оцениваемые объекты. (Чемпион мира имеет лучший рейтинг. Рейтинг президента падает.)
В то же время есть немало примеров употребления слова "рейтинг" в смысле "упорядоченный список". Например:
*В 2011 году Мельбурн поднялся со второго на первое место в рейтинге.*
[Рейтинг городов мира по уровню качества жизни](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8E_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Или вот в одном из вопросов: [место Вены в рейтинге.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432958/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-8/432964?noredirect=1#comment437971_432964)

Как правильно употреблять слово "рейтинг"?

И еще один вопрос возник по ходу: можно ли говорить "проводить рейтинг"? Это вводит еще одно значение для рейтинга: некое мероприятие по оценке (опрос?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, да. Рейтинг сейчас часто обозначает не столько показатель, сколько совокупность участников, "лист" здесь не совсем удачно из-за ложного друга переводчика, list — список. Возможно, поэтому его и оторвали в русском варианте.  Но ведь в английском наблюдается та же картина. Поэтому имеет смысл говорить об изменении значения самого слова, а не просто о сокращении слова для понятия "рейтинг-лист". И при этом надо разделять ситуации со списком оценок и с собственно оценкой.

"В 2011 году Мельбурн поднялся со второго на первое место в рейтинге" — это список. 
"Рейтинг городов мира по уровню качества жизни" — это показатель. Просто таблица с этими показателями.

Возможно, это и путает. А с другой стороны подтверждает, что понятия всё-таки отчасти взаимозаменяемые.

Использование "рейтинг" вместо "опрос" считаю некорректным.

Answer (score 3):

Упорядоченный список раньше называли "рейтинг-лист" (например, рейтинг-лист ФИДЕ), а теперь просто сократили до "рейтинга".